# Plotshape arrow does not appear on MACD crossover bar but mainly appears on subsequent bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I did some code so that an up arrow appears on the MACD when the MACD crosses over the MACD midline and a down arrow appears on the MACD when MACD crosses under the MACD midline.

Here is the relevant code I am using:

```
midline = 0
plotshape(ta.crossover(macd, midline) ? true : na,  'crossover', shape.triangleup, location.bottom, color.yellow, size=size.normal)
plotshape(ta.crossunder(macd, midline) ? true : na,  'crossover', shape.triangledown, location.top, color.yellow, size=size.normal)
```

However most of the times the up or down arrow does not appear exactly on the bar where the crossover or crossunder took place but on the next bar. This is not accurate.

What do I need to change in my code please to get the arrow to appear exactly on the bar where the crossover/crossunder took place?